# How can I use the value of a JQuery/Javascript variable in a Perl script?

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl, cgi

I am a complete newbie to Perl & Javascript/Jquery/Ajax. As an example, I'd like to send the string var `exampleString` to test.pl, and the script will then write the string to file.

```
function sendToScript{
    var exampleString = 'this is a string';
    $.ajax({
            url: './test.pl',
            data: exampleString,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('string saved to file');
            }
}
```

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

#How do I grab exampleString and set it to $string?

open (FILE, ">", "./text.txt") || die "Could not open: $!";
print FILE $string;
close FILE;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you want to send it using a get or post method?

Comment: @MikeB I had to look up the difference between the two, and I'd have to say neither? I simply want the perl script to grab the string variable `exampleString`, execute, and save the string to text file on the server; no data will be displayed client-side.

Comment: In that case you probably want to use the post method and just grab the entire body of the message. That said, and I'm not trying to be snarky, get and post are basic concepts of webapps; you probably should spend a little time learning about the tools you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like

```
var exampleString = 'this is a string';
$.ajax({
    url: './test.pl',
    data: {
        'myString' : exampleString
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('string saved to file');
    }
});
```

and test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use CGI ();
my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->header;
my $string = $cgi->param("myString");

open (FILE, ">", "./text.txt") || die "Could not open: $!";
print FILE $string;
close FILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) framework. It can be run under CGI, mod_perl, PSGI or its own built-in servers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

any '/' => 'index';

any '/save' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $output = 'text.txt';
  open my $fh, '>>', $output or die "Cannot open $output";
  print $fh $self->req->body . "\n";
  $self->render( text => 'Stored by Perl' );
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    %= t title => 'Sending to Perl'
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Sending</p>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    %= javascript begin
      function sendToScript (string) {
        $.post('/save', string, function (data) { alert(data) });
      }
      $(function(){sendToScript('this is a string')});
    % end
  </body>
</html>
```

save that to a file (say `test.pl`) and the run `./test.pl daemon` which will start the internal server.

Basically it sets up two routes, the `/` route is the user-facing page which runs the javascript request. The `/save` route is the one that the javascript posts the data to. The controller callback appends the full post body to the file and then sends a confirmation message back which is then displayed by the success javascript handler.