# How to use a Javascript value as a Perl variable

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

Is there a way to convert a javascript variable's value to a perl variable for use in the rest of the script?

The code that I have is:

```
  print "<TABLE border=22>";
  foreach $tmp (@splitarray) 
  {
    print "<TR>";
    $links = "<a href = '#' onclick='testingFunction(this);' >$tmp</a><BR>";
    print "<TD>$links</TD>";
  }
  print "<TD id='demo'></TD>";
  print "</TR>";
  print "</TABLE>";
}
print "<BR>";
print "<script type='text/javascript'>
       function testingFunction(link) 
       {
        var text = link.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = text;
       }
       </script>";

###Information about the group name that is clicked
print "
<TABLE border=1 cellpadding='10'>
<CAPTION id ='demo2'>
 <strong></strong>
</CAPTION>
<TR>
 <TD>Members of group:</TD>
 <TD>(Names)</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
 <TD>Jobs that group can do:</TD>
 <TD>(Jobs)</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>";
```

The split array variable is the group names. I would like to use the results from the javascript variable 'text' (which appear in the caption with the id of demo2) in other parts of my code but I would like for them to be stored as a Perl variable. For example, If a group that is clicked name is "Group 1" I would like the Perl variable $groupName to say "Group 1" when printed.

Even more specifically, my question is how do store the result of the Javascript OnClick event function in a perl variable?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work that way. When the content has been sent to a browser, the perl script finished it's execution long time ago. If you want to know what user did on his computer, you have to send those information again to your content generating program (server in most cases ;)).

You might want to read [This](http://webdesign.about.com/od/ajax/a/aa101705.htm).

Comment: I've never used AJAX before but I will look into it. There isn't a way to use Perl's param() function?

Comment: In fact the perl `param()` function would be useful, but first you have to pass a value of interest to your script. In other words if the content were sent to a client browser(he can manipulate data), that means the script finished its work some time ago. You have to find a way (like ajax) to send a value to it and then obtain params.

Comment: Using [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365793/how-can-i-use-the-value-of-a-jquery-javascript-variable-in-a-perl-script) I found an example kind of like what I wanted but the code didn't work when I did

Comment: print "<script type='text/javascript'>
        function testingFunction(link) {
    var text = link.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = text;
    $.ajax({
    url: './testScript.cgi',
    data: {
        'groupName' : text
            }
       };
    };


    </script>";


    $groupName = param('groupName');
    print $groupName;